# Polygon Smart Contract issue

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

Steps:

I have deployed a smart contract on Polygon Mumbai Testnet.
Granted role.
Start drop.
Approved several token URI
But the issue is that I am not able to mint now.
This is the error:

transact to NativzKeyMinter.mint errored: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
"code": 3,
"data": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001654686520707269636520697320696e636f727265637400000000000000000000",
"message": "execution reverted: The price is incorrect"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just search for require(PRICE_CONDITION,"The price is incorrect") inside your minting function of the smartcontract. Probably you are submiting zero value transaction, while the contract requires Matic tokens.